# Performing AJAX delete operations restfully in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

How do you perform delete and put operations restfully in rails? I have read the documentation and thought I was doing everything properly, but I can't seem to get it to work.

For example, if I wanted to delete an employee I would create a controller called "EmployeesController" and create a destroy method to perform the delete.

Then I went into the routes.rb file and entered `map.resources :employees`, which gives you access to the URL helper functions.

In whatever I want to call the Ajax operation from, I should just have a line like:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Delete", employee_path(@employee), :method => :delete %>
```

When I click on the link, it is still is sending a POST operation, so it does nothing.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
:url => employee_url(@employee)
```

IIRC, *_path is a named route generated by the :resource directive which includes the method, thus overwriting your :method => :delete

Answer (score 4):

From my code:

```
<%= link_to_remote "Delete", :url => post_url(post), :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a few extra details: Using `:url => employee_url(@employee)` helped (from the accepted answer). The other part that was messing me up was the fact that I was expecting an HTTP delete request, but I kept getting POST requests with a parameter "_method" (automatically added by rails) which was set to delete.

So it was calling the proper destroy action, which I proved by adding a couple of debug statements to the controller. Yes, my delete code was wrong in the controller, so it wasn't really deleting when I thought it was.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is not having AJAX request you have to add proper javascript tags